# Как прилинковать библиотеку box2d к проекту?

Tags: box2d, c++

Здравствуйте, научите, пожалуйста, как прилинковывать библиотеку к проекту в Visual Studio. Во всех учебниках находил только директивы #include, но мне этот способ не помогает...

Comment: В настройках проекта укажите правильный файл `.lib` для дебажной и релизной версии соответственно.

Comment: Правой кнопкой мыши на значке проекта в Solution Explorer-последний пунки Properties - Configuration Properties - Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies. .lib файлы надо положить в \Visual Studio 2012\VC\lib .h в \Visual Studio 2012\VC\include

Comment: @igumnov Тогда ваш проект не соберется ни у кого, кроме вас. Правильнее сложить библиотеки и их хэдеры в какую-нибудь папку в проекте и добавить эти пути в `Additional Library Directories` и `Additional Include Directories`.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать Все равно придется их копировать вместе с проектом если вдруг потребуется перенести на другой компьютер.

Comment: @igumnov Да, но в случае предложенного моего варианта вы, скажем, просто делаете `checkout / clone` из репозитория и проект собирается, а в случае предложенного вами варианта он не собирается :)

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать Если больше одного человека работает то тогда конечно Ваш вариант лучше. А тут какой-то парень просто хочет собрать BOX2D у себя дома.
  
@Alerr Configuration Properties - С/C++ Additional Include Directories. Configuration Properties - Linker - General - Additional Library Directories второй вариант что предлагает @Котик

Comment: Делал по последнему коментарию, указал пути на .h и на .lib...
Только вот что за ошибки?:
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>App.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall b2World::~b2World(void)" (??1b2World@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl AppMain(void)" (?AppMain@@YAXXZ)
1>App.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall b2World::b2World(struct b2Vec2 const &)" (??0b2World@@QAE@ABUb2Vec2@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl AppMain(void)" (?AppMain@@YAXXZ

Comment: А должен Box2D.h автоматически предлагаться при наборе #include<....?

Comment: Котик_хочет_кушать, а если нет релизной версии lib, то как быть?

Answer (score 2):

Вариант первый. Никаких .lib файлов. Создаете директорию в каталоге проекта, переносите туда сырцы вашей библиотеки, и позже добавляете их как ExistingItems
в самом проекте.

*Проверяйте пути в хэдерах/cpp-файлах и т.д. - очень даже может быть, что не предполагалось хранение этих файлов в одной директории, так что при переносе сохраняйте исходную иерархию каталогов.*

Компилируете.

Вариант второй - нужен .lib. Как справедливо заметили в комментариях - для каждой версии сборки нужна своя версия библиотеки. Тут - только хэдеры.

По поводу того, что у Вас в комментах - нужно указать в настройках проекта/Linker/CommandLine следующий ключ /NODEFAULTLIB:(название библиотеки из окна Errors). Но это может не помочь. Смотрите все сообщение - часто ошибки получаются из-за несовместимости некоторых настроек при сборке библиотеки и сборки проекта, например, чуть меньше, чем все из вкладки "CodeGeneration" ))

Кст., [тут](http://citforum.ru/book/cook/dll0.shtml) про динамические, но интересно ))